# 'TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON' in a Lerna workspace with CRA and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, node-sass, lerna

I have a Lerna Workspace with some packages and a webapp created with create-react-app using TypeScript.

When I try to add node-sass (needed for customizing ag-grid library themes, which I'm using in this project), I get the following error which I can't figure why it's happening:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'SourceFileObject'
    |     property 'statements' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'NodeObject'
    --- property 'parent' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at getBuildInfoText (path/to/project/packages/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:107932:21)
    at emitBuildInfo (path/to/project/packages/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:107709:67)
    at emitSourceFileOrBundle (path/to/project/packages/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:107674:13)
    at forEachEmittedFile (path/to/project/packages/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:107416:28)
    at Object.emitFiles (path/to/project/packages/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:107648:9)
    at Object.emitBuildInfo (path/to/project/packages/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:114560:33)
    at emitTsBuildInfoFileForBuilderProgram (path/to/project/packages/front/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/typescript-reporter/reporter/TypeScriptReporter.js:86:25)
    at path/to/project/packages/front/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/typescript-reporter/reporter/TypeScriptReporter.js:295:37
    at Object.afterProgramCreate (path/to/project/packages/front/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/typescript-reporter/reporter/ControlledWatchCompilerHost.js:15:17)
```

Due to it being a private project, I can't provide a snippet with the code.

Thanks in advance for any clue on how to solve a problem like this.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @PooriaKhodaveissi I had to upgrade Typescript in my project to fix this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this issue while upgrading a project to React `18.1.0`. In my case, upgrading Typescript to version `4.6.4` (the latest version at the time of writing) fixed it.

(I noticed the error message was coming from `typescript-reporter`, which was the clue I needed to upgrade Typescript.)